# string recursion problems

Tags: python, string

I am relatively new to python and especially recursion. 
I have been trying to solve this problem for a while now but it's bested me so far

I have to create a function that takes in 2 strings and uses recursion to see if elements from the first string are in the second string if so it returns true if not than it returns false
say "Carpool" and "prlo" or "elephant" and "xph" 
in the first case the recursive argument would return True and in the second case it would return False.

This is what I've been trying to do. I set a count so that if the elements match I can increase it and at the end if it's equal to len(str2) then I print 2. The major problem is iterating through the 2 strings separately, any idea on how I should approach this?

def compare(str1,str2):

```
count = 0
if str1 == str2:
    return "True"           
elif str1[0] == str2[0]:
    count = count + 1
    return letCheck (str1[1:],str2)
elif str1[0] != str2[0]:
    return letCheck (str1[1:],str2)
```

Comment: are you sure you have the outline of the function correct? Are you meant to check if each char of str1 is in str2?

Comment: So if i get this right you want to return `true` if `str1` shares characters with `str2` and count them as well?

Comment: to make it clear yes, I need to see if the char in str1 match the char in str2 order doesn't matter what order they appear in.
I don't have to count just return true if char from str2 appear in str1 as shown in the 2 examples

Comment: why did you not just use `in`, is there some requirement that prevents this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def compare(s1, s2):
    if not s2:
        return True
    elif s2[0] in s1:
        return compare(s1, s2[1:])
    else:
        return False
```

On your examples:

```
>>> compare( "Carpool" , "prlo")
True
>>> compare("elephant", "xph")
False
```

#### How it works

The function processes each character in string 2, `s2`, one at a time.  There are three cases:

1. If there are no characters left to process in `s2`, that means that all the tests have passed and we return True.
2. If there are still characters left in `s2`, then we test `s2[0]`. If it passes, we then use recursion to test the rest of the string.
3. If `s2[0]` is not in `s1`, then we have a fail and we return False.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a counter. You can just check if the first letter of the first String (str1) is in the second string (str2). If so, then check if this was the last character of the first string. If it wasn't the last character, pass the rest of the string to the function again (recursion).
And if one character of the first string is not in the second one, you return False.

```
def compare(str1, str2):
    if str1[0] in str2:
        if len(str1) == 1:
            return True;
        return compare(str[1:0], str2);
    else:
        return False;

print compare('ak', 'abcd');  # False
print compare('cd', 'abcd');  # True
print compare('efgh', 'efg'); # False
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return False if `str2` is passed in as an empty string:

```
def letCheck(str1, str2, count = 0):
    if str1 == str2: # both strings are equal,we don't have to  go any further
        return True
    elif str2 == "" and count == 0: # if str2 is empty and count is 0 we got passed an empty str2
        return False
    elif len(str2) == count: # if count and len are equal, all str2 letters are in str1
        return True
    elif str2[0] in str1:
        count += 1 # increase count and move to the next letter in str2[1:]
        return letCheck(str1, str2[1:],count)
    return False # if we get here we have found a letter that is not in str1
```

When using a variable like `count`, you need to use it as a parameter to keep the value between each `recursive` call or else it will get reset to `0` each call.